# how to "translate" Grep find/replace commands working with TextWrangler by a command line

Tags: replace, grep, textwrangler

I have some **Grep** find/replace commands working well under **TextWrangler** like the following one:

Find: (\"\d+.\d{3})+(\d{3}+[\s]+)

Replace: \1s

For example,this find/replace will replace:

*TXTXTXT"123.123456     TXTXTXT* 
by *TXTXTXT"123.123sTXTXTXT*

Now I want to do the same thing in command line by using egrep but it's not working:

```
egrep -e 's/(\"\d+\.\d{3})+(\d{3}+[\s]+)/\1s' -f m.txt > n.txt
```

egrep: Regular expression too big

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that the -f option reads the *regular expression* from a file. Just get rid of it. And lose the -e while you are at it. Just use:

```
egrep [regexp] [file] > [another file]
```

This, however, will leave you with another problem: grep just prints matches, it does not do substitutions. You should probably use sed instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try to use a grep command just because I have used the "grep mode" for the TextWrangler find/replace. Regarding sed, I made a little try but the syntax of the regex seems to be a little different.

Comment: I do not know TextWrangler, but "grep mode" is often just a nickname for regular expressions in general. In fact, the "re" in the middle of "grep" stands for "regular expression" - the ed command "g/re/p" would search globally for a regular expression and then print it.

Regular expressions are supported by many different tools, and their syntax often varies, but egrep (the e stands for extended regular expressions) and sed -r (the r stands for regular expressions extended, because -e was already taken) should be similar enough to manage. Give it a try.